# How to reverse a integer array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, integer, reverse

How to reverse an `integer array` in swift

eg: `var ab = [1,2,3,4]`

I want to store the array in reverse format.

The result should be

```
ab = [4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+array+reverse) before posting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use ab.reversed() function which returns a reversed array.

Answer (score 3):

```
var ab = [1, 2, 3, 4]

func reverse(_ arr: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    return arr.reversed() // we return here
}
print(reverse(ab))  // The answer print as you need! [4, 3, 2, 1]
```